# Azure DevOps: How to download a file from git using REST API?

Tags: python, azure

Following the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

I can query a dev ops organization and get a response like so:

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "value": [
    {
      "objectId": "61a86fdaa79e5c6f5fb6e4026508489feb6ed92c",
      "gitObjectType": "blob",
      "commitId": "23d0bc5b128a10056dc68afece360d8a0fabb014",
      "path": "/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views/Home/_Home.cshtml",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views/Home/_Home.cshtml?versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I use Python to, I guess, download that url? The file should be an XML file. I want to read (download) it directly from Python.

If I take the `url` returned above and insert it into yet another `GET` request, I get sent in loops basically.

### Edit:

I figured out that if I paste the URL that it gives me, I can download the file with my web browser. However, when I insert that same URL into a new `request`, I get the same meta-data over and over, trying:

```
response = requests.get(url=(url), headers=headers, stream=True)
response.text
response.content

response = requests.get(url=(url), headers=headers, stream=False)
response.text
response.content
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download a file over HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-to-download-a-file-over-http)

Comment: No -- even I insert the `url` into yet another GET request, I get more urls.

Comment: You don't appear to be changing the `url` variable, so I would expect the content to be the same?

Comment: I do change the variable, it's just an illustration of stream off / on as one possible reason

Comment: Looking at the documentation you shared it seems like you need to set the `download` parameter to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem, as both comments and previous answer are incorrect and will not lead you to the right answer for future visitors.

Following the example here as originally posted, it presumes that `download=True`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

However, you then need to query the file of interest and set this flag: `&includeContent=true` to actually get the file content from the devops GIT.

Like so:

```
https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items?scopePath=/MyWebSite/MyWebSite/Views/Home/_Home.cshtml&includeContent=true&api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

or you will send as many GET requests as you like and get nothing of value in return.